# How to go to question list from a question on unsaved StackExchange site?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, help

I typically like to browse through various Stack Exhange sites in which I'm not registered yet. And at times I want to see list of questions after I read one question on that site. Tapping on the site icon brings me to the left side panel, from which I cannot choose the site I'm currently at, since I'm not registered in it.

Is there a way to go to question list from the question view? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: The back button works for me. Unless you somehow arrived at the question  from somewhere other than the question list?

Comment: That is true if you access the question from the question list. But I'm talking about the case when your previous screen is not the question list, say, from your homepage.

Comment: I see. The shortest way I could find is to tap some tag in the question, which brings up tag-filtered view of that site. Then clear the filter by tapping x symbol in the box.

Comment: Wah, that trick works. Although I guess we should still be able to tap on the site name above to get back to question list, I guess?